# Is it normal that a pure math student doesn't know vector analysis?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Today I was watching a series of online video lectures about electromagnetism. At some point of the lecture, the professor used this vector calculus identity: $$ \nabla\times\left(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}\right)=\mathbf{A}\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}\right)-\mathbf{B}\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}\right)+\left(\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf{A}-\left(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf{B}$$

So, I tried to prove it by using the "bac-cab" identity and I kept getting wrong results. Later, I realized that the "bac-cab" identity for vector triple products doesn't hold anymore when vector operators like $\nabla$ are involved!

Is it normal that I don't know any vector analysis? I've taken multi-variable calculus, but they didn't teach us anything about such identities! Did my university cheat on us and taught us less than we should know or it's normal for pure math students not to know vector analysis identities as well as engineers and physicists know them?

And at last, I'll appreciate it if someone introduces a good introductory book about vector calculus that teaches me how to deal with such vector equations and identities.

Comment: Yes. The first time I did this stuff seriously was in a graduate PDE course. I've taken a lot of math classes and I honestly don't know what you mean by taking the cross product of a $\nabla$ and a vector. To answer your second question, don't bother. Learn it if and when you need to use it.

Comment: I didn't (still don't) know this identity and I don't feel cheated at all. This seems like something for the physicists.

Comment: "Normal is just a setting on the washing machine." I never took several variable calculus, jumping straight to real analysis, and also didn't take much physics, so I never learned various common operators.

Comment: I've heard good things about Schey's _Div Grad Curl And All That._

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Same. I never took Calc III. I don't regret that choice.

Comment: I've only regretted it the few times I've dipped my toes into physics. @Potato

Comment: Perfectly normal. Pure mathematicians use differential forms rather than vector calculus.

Comment: @DanielFischer: So, if someone masters the calculus of differential forms and exterior algebras in higher levels, they don't need to learn vector calculus anymore? I'm still a freshman, but I hope that when I learn more mathematics I become able to study quantum mechanics. Do I need to learn vector calculus on my own for that?

Comment: But the best way to approach this identity is to rewrite it via index notation ( e.g. $\sum_j \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j \epsilon_{klm} A_l B_m$) where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita tensor. The identity follows from combining the product rule with trading $\epsilon$'s for Kronecker $\delta$'s.

Comment: @math.n00b I think, practically speaking, it's still useful to know the vector calculus formulation (because that's what all the physics textbooks use). However, if I recall correctly, quantum is all about Hilbert spaces and doesn't really use vector calculus.

Comment: Also, the math for quantum is more in the realm of vector spaces not vector calculus. (Vector calc does come up in _deriving_ the relevant interactions of quantum systems e.g. the dipole interaction of an electron with a field. But the quantum mechanics used to calculate that only uses this an input)

Comment: @math.n00b From a theoretical standpoint, there is no need for vector calculus if you know differential forms. Practically, however, if you enter into areas where people habitually use vector calculus, you'd better be somewhat comfortable with that too. (Somewhat like, you don't need to know Italian to study literature, but if you want to become a Dante expert, you better learn Italian, pronto.)

Comment: @semiclassical: Do you study physics? If yes, can you please tell me when physicists use vector calculus nowadays?

Comment: @mathnoob, for QM you don't need vector calculus, mostly linear algebra, Jackson's classical electrodynamics is a good start if you want to both apply vector calculus and learn electromagnetism!

Comment: I do (I'm a theoretical physics grad student, actually). The essential place of application is in electromagnetism, especially in practical application. It also comes in for classical mechanics e.g. forces, torques.

Comment: I'd suggest Griffith's E&M as a more introductory text. Jackson is at the graduate level.

Comment: @Semiclassical: I see. Well, I'm studying electromagnetism because I need to know it to fully appreciate the ideas behind relativity. Is that right? or I don't need to know electromagnetism to understand physics undergraduate textbooks?

Comment: @mathnoob if you want a gentler and more general view of the relationship btn SR and EM then i suggest you check  out Feynman's lectures on physics vol II

Comment: Depends a bit on what precisely you want to understand about relativity. It won't be of much relevance for certain concepts.

Comment: @pkjag: Do Feynman lectures teach physics in a rigorous and academic way or they've been written for the general public like Hawking's books? :P I'm sorry, I've never checked Feynman's lectures on physics. Will I benefit, academically, from reading his lectures?

Comment: They are definitely worth a read, though they don't have problems at the end of any chapter, they are a must have for any serious person who self studies physics

Comment: For special relativity, it's hard to beat the mathematical simplicity and clarity of Resnicks text. http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Special-Relativity-Robert-Resnick/dp/0471717258 . Also, if you want to look at calculus III written by someone who cares about $\nabla$ and curvelinear coordinates you might look at http://www.supermath.info/OldCalculusIIIresources.html see pages 360-425 or for my recent edit with a bit less of topics http://www.supermath.info/CalculusIIIf2014.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments made thus far give excellent advice. I thought you might like to see the details.

We need the well-known identity $\sum_{j=1}^{3} \epsilon_{ikj}\epsilon_{lmj} = \delta_{il}\delta_{km}-\delta_{kl}\delta_{im}$. This is the dark heart of the BAC-CAB identity.
\begin{align} \notag
 \nabla \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B}) 
&= \sum_{i,j,k=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk}\partial_i (\vec{A} \times \vec{B})_j\widehat{x}_k \\ 
&= \sum_{i,j,k=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk}\partial_i \left(\sum_{l,m=1}^3A_lB_m\epsilon_{lmj} \right) \widehat{x}_k \\ 
&= \sum_{i,j,k=1}^3\sum_{l,m=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmj}\partial_i \left(A_lB_m \right) \widehat{x}_k \\ 
&= -\sum_{i,j,k,l,m=1}^3 \color{red}{\epsilon_{ikj}\epsilon_{jlm}}\partial_i \left(A_lB_m \right) \widehat{x}_k \\ 
&= -\sum_{i,k,l,m=1}^3( \color{red}{\delta_{il}\delta_{km}-\delta_{im}\delta_{kl}})\partial_i \left(A_lB_m \right) \widehat{x}_k \\ 
&= -\sum_{i,k,l,m=1}^3\delta_{il}\delta_{km}\partial_i \left(A_lB_m \right) \widehat{x}_k+\sum_{i,k,l,m=1}^3\delta_{im}\delta_{kl}\partial_i \left(A_lB_m \right) \widehat{x}_k \\ 
&= -\sum_{i,k=1}^3\partial_i \left(A_iB_k \right) \widehat{x}_k+\sum_{i,k=1}^3\partial_i \left(A_kB_i \right) \widehat{x}_k \\ 
&= -\sum_{i,k=1}^3\left((\partial_i A_i)B_k+A_i\partial_i B_k \right) \widehat{x}_k+\sum_{i,k=1}^3 \left((\partial_iA_k)B_i+A_k\partial_iB_i \right) \widehat{x}_k \\ 
&= -\sum_{i,k=1}^3(\partial_i A_i)B_k\widehat{x}_k-\sum_{i,k=1}^3A_i\partial_i B_k\widehat{x}_k  +\sum_{i,k=1}^3 B_i\partial_iA_k\widehat{x}_k+\sum_{i,k=1}^3(\partial_iB_i)A_k \widehat{x}_k \\ 
&= -(\nabla \cdot \vec{A})\vec{B}-(\vec{A} \cdot \nabla  )\vec{B}+(\nabla \cdot \vec{B})\vec{A}+(\vec{B} \cdot \nabla  )\vec{A}
\end{align}
If it's any consolation, I was a math & physics double major and this stuff escaped me until I had the good fortune in graduate school of studying with a student from Spain. I had pages and pages of stuff and he had three lines on a particular problem. It hit me, I probably should use $\epsilon_{ijk}$ for vector identity calculations. Moreover, there is a whole family of contracting levi-civita symbols as sums of antisymmetric kronecker deltas. The identity this post begins with is just a start. These are used in the tensor calculus of General Relativity.

Comment: The only unfortunate thing is the profusion of dummy indices in such a calculation. It's why I always liked the _idea_ of Penrose notation for such things, though since I don't do GR myself I've never needed their full power.

Comment: @Semiclassical well, at first dummies are a bit unsettling (hence their absence in my calculation here intended for math audience) but, after a few hundred pages of calculation and omitting a few thousand $\sum$ symbols, you get numb to the abuse.  In truth, it is very freeing, in combination with multi-index notation, you can say so much with so little. That said, I am not versed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation . Interesting.

Comment: True enough. I more just mean how tedious those indices become, and the fact that in Penrose notation they just end up as lines. But again, not very practical for the typical physicist.

Comment: @Semiclassical incidentally, you might like http://www.physicsoverflow.org/ I haven't said much of use there yet, but it seems like a good community to support.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I guess I'll have to find some more vector calculus identities and try to prove them on my own. But wait, what is $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{\nabla}$? I mean, how does that even make sense? How should we interpret $(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{\nabla})\vec{B}$?

Comment: @math.n00b there is a marked difference between the first two terms in the identity in your post. For instance, we could just as well write $(\nabla \cdot \vec{A} )\vec{B}$ or $\vec{B}(\nabla \cdot \vec{A} )$ either way, we're just scalar multiplying the divergence of $\vec{A}$ on $\vec{B}$. The term $\vec{A} \cdot \nabla$ is a differential operator. It is no longer the case we can exchange the order of the last two terms as, for instance, $(\vec{A} \cdot \nabla) \vec{B} \neq \vec{B}(\vec{A} \cdot \nabla)$. On the lhs is a vector, on the rhs an operator. More to the point ...

Comment: $\vec{A} \cdot \nabla = A_x \partial_x+A_y \partial_y+A_z \partial_z$. The trap is that we are so accustomed to using $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B} = \vec{B} \cdot \vec{A}$ for vectors that we are tempted to suppose it applies to operators, but, it doesn't. The notation $\nabla \cdot \vec{A}$ and $\vec{A} \cdot \nabla$ are quite different.

Comment: Thanks. Please check my post below you. I've tried to apply what I've learned from your post on other vector calculus identities. Please check if I've understood the calculations correctly, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to prove two other vector calculus identities to check if I've understood physicists notations well :D I'm going to use Einstein's summation notation as well. ;-)

1.
  $$\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) = \mathbf{B} \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) - \mathbf{A} \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{B})$$

$$\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) = \partial_i(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B})_i=\partial_i(\epsilon_{ijk}A_jB_k)=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_i(A_jB_k)=\epsilon_{ijk}A_j\partial_iB_k+\epsilon_{ijk}B_k\partial_iA_j$$

$$\epsilon_{ijk}A_j\partial_iB_k+\epsilon_{ijk}B_k\partial_iA_j=-\epsilon_{jik}A_j\partial_iB_k+\epsilon_{kij}B_k\partial_iA_j=-A_j(\epsilon_{jik}\partial_iB_k)+B_k(\epsilon_{kij}\partial_iA_j)$$
$$-A_j(\epsilon_{jik}\partial_iB_k)+B_k(\epsilon_{kij}\partial_iA_j)=-A_j(\nabla \times \mathbf{B})_j+B_k(\nabla \times \mathbf{A})_k = -\mathbf{A}\cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{B})+\mathbf{B}\cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{A})$$

2.
$$ \nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \mathbf{A} \right) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}) - \nabla^{2}\mathbf{A}$$

where $\nabla^{2}\mathbf{A}=\langle \nabla^{2}A_x, \nabla^{2}A_y, \nabla^{2}A_z\rangle$ and it's called vector Laplacian.

$$(\nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \mathbf{A} \right))_i = \epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(\nabla\times \mathbf{A})_k=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(\epsilon_{kmn}\partial_mA_n)=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{kmn}\partial_j(\partial_mA_n)$$
Now we use the famous equality: $$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{kmn}=\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}$$

$$(\nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \mathbf{A} \right))_i= \delta_{im}\delta_{jn}\partial_j(\partial_mA_n)-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}\partial_j(\partial_mA_n)=\partial_j(\partial_iA_j)-\partial_j(\partial_jA_i)$$
$$\partial_j(\partial_iA_j)-\partial_j(\partial_jA_i)=\partial_i(\partial_jA_j)-(\partial_j\partial_j)A_i=\partial_i(\nabla \cdot\mathbf{A})-(\nabla^{2}\mathbf{A})_i=(\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A})-\nabla^{2}\mathbf{A})_i$$

I'm sure that the last line needs some modifications because the LHS is the i-th component of $\nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \mathbf{A} \right)$ while in RHS a vector ($\nabla^{2}\mathbf{A}$) has showed up sooner than it should appear.

So, I've made the following assumptions in my calculations (Please verify them):

1. Partials *always* act like differentials, *regardless of the subscripts involved in our calculations*. $\partial_iX_jY_k = (\partial_iX_j)Y_k + X_j(\partial_iY_k)$.
2. If we assume the existence and continuity of second derivatives involved in our calculations, then since partial derivatives commute we have $\partial_i\partial_j= \partial_j\partial_i$.
3. I've assumed that $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is a constant function and it can come out of partial derivatives with ease.

**EDIT:**

I want to prove that:

$$ \nabla(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}) = (\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{B} + (\mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{B}) + \mathbf{B} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) $$

$$(\nabla(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}))_i = \partial_i (\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B})=\partial_i(A_jB_j)=\partial_i(A_j)B_j+\partial_i(B_j)A_j$$

I don't see how I should move forward. I'm stuck.

Comment: Nearly perfect, however, in the last line we should have $\partial_i (\nabla \cdot \vec{A})-\nabla^2 A_i = (\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec{A})- \nabla^2 \vec{A})_i$. Which, is what you want as you calculated the $i$-th component of $\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec{A})$. Nice work!

Comment: In addition to that little note by Mr. Cook, I'd just like to add: 1) Make sure you realize *why* you can pull the $\epsilon_{ijk}$ in and out of the differential operators (so you know exactly when it's allowable).  2) I think you might want to be more careful about commuting factors. Technically the Leibniz rule states that $\partial_i(X_jY_k) = (\partial_iX_j) Y_k + X_j \partial_iY_k$.  The factors *do* commute because they are scalars, but I'd just be more explicit.  3) I consider $\partial_j^2$ to be an abuse of notation.  In that form it looks like there's only 1 index...

Comment: and so can fool you or your readers when using the Einstein summation convention.  I prefer to just leave it as $\partial_j \partial_j$.  If you can keep those things in mind, then yeah, I think you've got it.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: Yes, I'd already noticed that but I was unsure whether $$\partial_j\partial_jA_i=\nabla^{2}A_i=(\nabla^{2}\mathbf{A})_i$$ was correct or not, later I verified it. Thanks for your help. I'm trying to prove that $$ \nabla(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}) = (\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{B} + (\mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{B}) + \mathbf{B} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) $$ but I keep getting wrong results, I don't see how the cross product comes into the play. Would you please give me a hint?

Comment: @Bye_world: Yes, thanks for your notes. I can pull $\epsilon_{ijk}$ out because it's a constant, not a function. No? And now it makes more sense why writing $\partial^{2}_j$ is a bad idea.. because if there's only one $j$ index it won't be summed over. Right?

Comment: @math.n00b for the $\nabla (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B})$ calculation, I recommend starting with the cross product terms then using the double $\epsilon$-identity on each term. A direct assault would seem to require you changing $\delta$-'s back into $\epsilon$ which requires a bit more imagination.

Comment: @math.noob Technically a function *could* be pulled out of the differential as long as it *didn't depend on the differential variables*.  For instance, if you have $\partial_i (f(t)g(x,y,z))$, where your $\partial_i$ are the components of $\nabla = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z})$ and where $t$ was NOT a function of $x, y,$ or $z$, then you could pull out the $f(t)$.  I just wanted to make sure you realized that (because no one explained why I could do that when I first learned it).  And as for the $\partial_j^2$, you're exactly right.

Comment: @math.noob I had a difficult vector identity to solve one day -- it may have even been the one you're stuck on -- that I spent something like **4 hours** trying to get to the RHS from the LHS.  Then on a whim, I decided to go the other direction (that is, start with the RHS) -- it took me less than 10 minutes.  I learned a lesson that day: sometimes identities are **much** easier to prove in one direction than the other.  Hope that helps! :)